# Generating bezier handles based on constraints

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, bezier-curve

I want to try to emulate what this application can do:

[alt text http://img530.imageshack.us/img530/5756/bezier.png](http://img530.imageshack.us/img530/5756/bezier.png)

Given the red round dots (from the mouse) it is able to solve for the bezier handles given that the tension of the curve is set to $0.6$. How could I solve for the bezier handles? Is there some way I could do this with the slope or perpendicular of the previous and next curve?

Thanks

*I should also add that each point is equidistant meaning point $i + 1$ is the distance to point $i$ or point $i + 2$.

Comment: With no image, it's impossible to know what the (now-deleted) user was asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the graphic, it appears that the handles at a given point $p_k$ are parallel to the line through $p_{k-1}$ and $p_{k+1}$ and that the lengths of the handles at every point are equal.  I suspect that the length of the handles is determined by the "tension" that you mention.